# std::sort for a 2D vector in c++

Tags: c++, sorting, stdvector

I have a 2D vector `InputVector` defined as follows:

```
vector< vector<int> > InputVector(MAX_ITER, vector<int>(inN));
```

There is another vector `CR` defined as follows:

```
vector<int> CR(MAX_ITER);
```

`CR[i]` is a property related to `InputVector[i]`(notice `i` can vary from `0` to `MAX_ITER-1` for both). Now I want to sort `InputVector` in decreasing order of `CR`, i.e., if `CR[j]` is the highest among all `CR's`, `InputVector[j]` should be the new `InputVector[0]` after sorting. 
Can this be done using `std::sort` defined in `algorithm`?

Comment: Do you want to sort `CR` at the same time? If you don't, then the `InputVector` and `CR` arrays will be inconsistent after the sort. More importantly, do you have to have this data structure with two separate arrays? A better structure would be `vector< pair< vector<int>, int> >` where the second element in the pair is the `CR` property.

Comment: @TooTone Completely agree. But I wasn't comfortable dealing with such complex structure. Like let's say I had to pass just `InputVector` to a function, then will passing `InputVectorCR.first` be correct? Here `InputVectorCR` is `vector< pair< vector<int>, int> >`. Also how I would sort it in that case. Also if you are going to answer it, please answer it as an answer rather than comment.

Comment: no, that's the disadvantage of putting them in the same structure like that. You'd have to consider wrapping the whole thing in a class etc.

Comment: I wish to do it without class. A class will be an overkill(I guess).

Comment: fair enough, and the other question I asked -- do you want to sort `CR` at the same time? -- because if you don't, then the `InputVecto`r and `CR` arrays will be inconsistent after the sort.

Comment: Yes, I do want to sort `CR` at the same time.

Comment: If I take `InputVectorCR` as `vector< pair<int, vector<int> > >`, and then call `sort(InputVectorCR.begin(), InputVectorCR.end())` will it get sorted? I mean in the ascending order.

Comment: you'd have to write a custom less than operator, which isn't difficult. But if your constraint is to keep your data structures separate there might be a better way.

Comment: Also how do I declare `InputVectorCR` of size `MAX_ITER*inN`. I mean `InputVector` can be declared like this: `vector< vector<int> > InputVector(MAX_ITER, vector<int>(inN));`. But what how to do that for `InputVectorCR`? Please just answer this one, I wont disturb you more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a weird task, but it can be done.

I would say - push_back the CR[j] value to the InputVector[j], then write a custom 'less' function which compares last elements and pop_back the CR[j] values. Something like that:

But it seems you should really reconsider how you store your data - the fact that you need such logic is a warning bell.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
typedef vector<vi> vvi;

struct last_cmp
{
    bool operator()(const vi &lhs, const vi &rhs)
    {
        return lhs.back() > rhs.back();
    }
};

void weird_sort(vvi &InputVector, const vi &CR)
{
    assert(InputVector.size() == CR.size());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < InputVector.size(); i++)
        InputVector[i].push_back(CR[i]);

    sort(InputVector.begin(), InputVector.end(), last_cmp());

    for (size_t i = 0; i < InputVector.size(); i++)
        InputVector[i].pop_back();
}

int main()
{
    vvi InputVector;
    vi CR;

    InputVector.push_back(vector<int>(5, 0));
    InputVector.push_back(vector<int>(5, 1));
    InputVector.push_back(vector<int>(5, 2));
    InputVector.push_back(vector<int>(5, 3));
    InputVector.push_back(vector<int>(5, 4));

    CR.push_back(3);
    CR.push_back(2);
    CR.push_back(0);
    CR.push_back(1);
    CR.push_back(4);

    weird_sort(InputVector, CR);

    for (int i = 0; i < InputVector.size(); i++)
        cout << InputVector[i][0] << endl;
}
```

Comment: If I take `InputVectorCR` as `vector< pair<int, vector<int> > >`, and then call `sort(InputVectorCR.begin(), InputVectorCR.end())` will it get sorted? I mean in the ascending order.

Comment: You should still provide the custom 'less' function which will compare the first elements of the pair. The simple call sort(InputVectorCR.begin(), InputVectorCR.end()) will not work.

Comment: this is a good answer, better than mine in fact because you've spotted a very nice hack. But it's not quite correct because the OP wants to sort `CR` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think a new class or using pair would be better but if you really want to do it

```
std::sort(InputVector.begin(), InputVector.end(), 
    [&CR,&InputVector](std::vector<int> &a, std::vector<int> &b){
        auto pos_a = &a - &(*InputVector.begin());
        auto pos_b = &b - &(*InputVector.begin());
        return (CR[pos_a] < CR[pos_b]);}
        );
```

This works in the small test I made, but I think it could be dangerous.

Comment: are you saying it could land one in ... danger zone ?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments under your question you clarify that you'd prefer to keep the two arrays separate rather than combining them, and also that you'd like to sort `CR` as well as `InputVector`. In that case the simplest approach is to create a temporary array that zips the two arrays into one, use `std::sort`, then unzip back into the original two arrays.

The zipping and unzipping should not slow things down too much: these are O(n) whereas sorting is O(n log n). Moreover, assuming the bulk of your data is contained in the nested `vector<int>`s in  `InputVector`, this data can be moved to and from the temporary array using `vector::swap`, which as the name suggests, swaps around the underlying data rather than copying it.

```
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <algorithm>

void Sort(vector< vector<int> > &InputVector, vector<int>& CR) // assumes vectors the same size
{
    struct CRIntVec
    {
        int CR;
        vector<int> IntVec;
        bool operator<(const CRIntVec& rhs) const
        { return CR > rhs.CR; } // sort in descending order
    };
    vector<CRIntVec> combinedVec(InputVector.size());
    // Copy CR to combined vector but for efficiency swap in InputVector 
    for(int i=0; i<InputVector.size(); ++i) {
        combinedVec[i].CR = CR[i];
        combinedVec[i].IntVec.swap(InputVector[i]);
    }
    // Sort the combined vector
    std::sort(combinedVec.begin(), combinedVec.end());
    // Copy back from combined vector to CR, once again swapping for efficiency
    for(int i=0; i<InputVector.size(); ++i) {
        CR[i] = combinedVec[i].CR;
        combinedVec[i].IntVec.swap(InputVector[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could, but it would be prohibitively expensive. You would have to do sequential searches on `CR` for each member of `InputVector`, to get its relative sort value. It's not impossible, but very inefficient.

To make it more efficient make `CR` a map, or a hash-table.